# -bash: eval: line 109: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: bash

```
if [[ -s $GCMS_ENV && -r $GCMS_ENV ]]
then

    echo "">/dev/null        ##file exists
    if [[ -s $GCMS_PRIV_ENV && -r $GCMS_PRIV_ENV ]]

    then

            egrep  "[A-Z]?=.[a-zA-Z0-9]?" $GCMS_PRIV_ENV  | grep -v ^# 2>/dev/null 1> $TMP_FILE
            egrep  "[A-Z]?=.[a-zA-Z0-9]?" $GCMS_ENV | grep -v ^# 2>/dev/null 1>> $TMP_FILE
    else
            egrep  "[A-Z]?=.[a-zA-Z0-9]?" $GCMS_ENV | grep -v ^# 2>/dev/null 1> $TMP_FILE
    fi
    {


            while read RECORD
            do
                    VAR=$(echo $RECORD|cut -s -d$DELIM -f1)
                    VAL=$(echo $RECORD|cut -s -d$DELIM -f2-9)
                    eval export $VAR=$VAL
            done
    }<$TMP_FILE

else

    echo "\n$THIS_FILE\n error:"
    echo "The file $GCMS_ENV does not exist, no environment settings!"
    return 1
fi
```

i am trying to run folllowing kSH shell in my linux box while running the same i am facing the following error.

> -bash: eval: line 109: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>
> -bash: eval: line 110: syntax error: unexpected end of file

please let me know anybody have a answer for the same

Comment: I do not see any unterminated string in that code. However, I can't see anything that would prevent tokens after `grep -v ^#` from being ignored as comments, and I can't find the opening brace matching the closing one in `}<$TMP_FILE`.

Comment: [ yes...opening brce is there next above the while staement..now edited still am getting the error.]

Comment: @user3588857 Please post the whole script.

Comment: Also be aware that while you state you are "trying to run following kSH shell", the error message indicates that the script is executed by `bash`, not `ksh`. Seconding konsolebox -- getting an error message with line number is useless if you aren't posting the whole script, or **at least** indicate which lines you posted are number 109 / 110...

Comment: Please post the result of `cat -n yourscript`.

Comment: [109-->VAL=$(echo $RECORD|cut -s -d$DELIM -f2-9)
110-->eval export $VAR=$VAL
  these are the two lines, if u want i acn pate the whole script.]

Comment: @user3588857: Well... what's the contents of `$RECORD` at that point? What's the content of `$DELIM`? What is the output of `echo $RECORD | cut -s -d$DELIM -f2-9`? Come on, do some debugging, it's not rocket science...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: See, the reply pointed me to the fact that the script probably doesn't have any unmatched `"` to begin with, it's the input (and it's processing) that's at fault...

Comment: @DevSolar, all right, even in this specific case you win :)

Comment: There is probably an unmatched `"` in the input to the `eval` command causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` should be avoided whenever possible, especially when it is probably responsible for the syntax error you observe. Use this in place of your `while` loop.

```
while read -d"$DELIM" VAR VAL; do
    declare -x "$VAR=$VAL"
done < "$TMP_FILE"
```

You may still have an error that `eval` triggered, so double check your input files to make sure the assignments have matched `"`.